# nodejs + mongoose - how to use forEach in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm still learning about node.js and mongodb. I'm trying to write simple app with nodejs and mongoose. My mongoose schema:

```
var todoSchema = new Schema({
  task: String,
  description: String,
  date: Date,
  status: String,
  checklist: Boolean,
  pic: String
});
```

I have collection named `todos` I'm trying to get the content of `todos` using this code:

```
apiRoutes.route('/todos/detail')
.get(function(req, res){
    Todo.distinct( "pic" ).each(function(doc){
        Todo.find({"pic": doc.pic}, function(err, todo){
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        var finalResult = [];
        finalResult.push(todo);
        res.send(finalResult);
        });
    });
});
```

But I got this error:

```
Object #<Query> has no method 'each'
```

Any idea to solve this? Really appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I gather in your question, you don't necessarily need the loop since with the distinct pics array you are iterating over, you are using it to query the collection for each pic, which is
essentially equivalent to just querying the whole collection as sending the resulting array of documents returned from the query:

```
apiRoutes.route('/todos/detail').get(function(req, res){
    Todo.find({"pic": { "$exists": true }}, function(err, todos){
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.send(todos);
    });
});
```

Unless you want to get a distinct list of pics, get the todo items with those pics you could try the following approach:

```
apiRoutes.route('/todos/detail').get(function(req, res){
    Todo.find().distinct('pic', function(error, pics) {
        // pics is an array of all pics
        Todo.find({"pic": { "$in": pics } }, function(err, todos){
            if (err) res.send(err);
            res.send(todos);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hi @chridam thank you for your help. it worked. really appreciated it :)

Answer (score 0):

For starting you should try with `.forEach()` instead of `.each()` first :)
Here you can see the [forEach doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach).